# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text', beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, text, beautifulsoup

When i try to run the code and export it to csv. the error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'" appears and I hace tried every way to fix it but nothing seems to be working.The ProductName Prints out but the Price is the one causing the error

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    import csv
    
    csv_file = open('CultBeauty.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Product Name','Price'])
    
    for i in range(10):
        url = requests.get('https://www.cultbeauty.com/skin-care.list?pageNumber={}&facetFilters=en_beauty_skincareSkinType_content:Dry'.format(i+1)).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
        lists = soup.find_all('div', class_= "productBlock")
        for list in lists:
            ProductName = list.find('h3', class_="productBlock_productName")
            ProductName= ProductName.text.strip()
            print(ProductName)
            Price = list.find('span', {'class' : "productBlock_priceValue"})
            Price = Price.text.strip()
            print(Price)
            csv_writer.writerow([ProductName,Price])
    csv_file.close()


output:
Paula's Choice Skin Perfecting 2% BHA Liquid Exfoliant (118ml)
36.00€
Paula's Choice Skin Perfecting 25% AHA and 2% BHA Exfoliant Peel 30ml
44.00€
Sunday Riley GOOD GENES Glycolic Acid Treatment 1.7 fl. oz.
140.00€
BYOMA Hydrating Serum 30ml
14.60€
Elemis Pro-Collagen Cleansing Balm 100g
51.90€
BYOMA Moisturising Gel Cream 50ml
13.50€
Paula's Choice Skin Perfecting 2% BHA Liquid Exfoliant - Trial Size (30ml)
12.00€
etc

but it doesn't save to csv file and brings out the error
```

Comment: What the error means is that either `ProductName` or `Price` is empty -- the element was not found.  You're not doing any error checking here, and you didn't tell us which item triggers the error.

Comment: The ProductName Prints out but the Price is the one causing the error

Comment: `list.find('span', {'class' : "productBlock_priceValue"})` did not find any elements, and so it returned `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some list of items may not have price value.So you might  use `try except` and also need to add `user-agent` . It always be better practice  not using list as variable as list is a python keyword. Now it's working smoothly.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

csv_file = open('CultBeauty.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['Product Name', 'Price'])
headers={"User-Agent":"mozilla/5.0"}
for i in range(10):
    url = requests.get('https://www.cultbeauty.com/skin-care.list?pageNumber={}&facetFilters=en_beauty_skincareSkinType_content:Dry'.format(i+1),headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
    lists = soup.find_all('div', class_="productBlock")
    for lis in lists:
        ProductName = lis.find('h3', class_="productBlock_productName")
        ProductName = ProductName.text.strip()
        print(ProductName)
        try:
            Price = lis.find('span', {'class': "productBlock_priceValue"})
            Price = Price.text.strip()
            print(Price)
        except:
            pass
        csv_writer.writerow([ProductName, Price])
csv_file.close()
```